# PostgreSQL: Turn jsonb into another table

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have table `_book` with `jsonb` column:

| id | doc_id | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 59ba6f9e | 1 | {"text": "test", "attachments": [{"size": 59934, "storageId": "38f2"}]} |
| bd402b1e | 2 | {"text": "", "attachments": [{"size": 52512, "type": "PASS", storageId": "4178"}, {"size": 525128, "type": "DKP", "storageId": "2179"}]} |
| abf467d2 | 2 | {"text": "", "attachments": []} |
| b412320b | 1 | {"text": "", "attachments": [{"size": 36238, "type": "PASS", "storageId": "8916"}, {"size": 36238, "type": "PASS", "storageId": "791b"}]} |

where: `attachments` may be empty, `type` may not be among the fields of an object in `jsonb`.

I need migrate this to table `_doc` without jsonb.

table `_doc`:

| doc_id | size | type | storage_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 59934 |  | 38f2 |
| 2 | 52512 | PASS | 4178 |
| 2 | 52528 | DKP | 2179 |
| 1 | 36238 | PASS | 8916 |
| 1 | 26231 | PASS | 791b |

This is my query for getting all rows where the `attachments` from `jsonb` column is not empty

```
select doc_id,
       jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'attachments') ->> 'size' as size,
       jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'attachments') ->> 'type' as type,
       jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'attachments') ->> 'storageId' as document_storage_id
from _book
where JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH(data -> 'attachments') > 0
order by created_at;
```

But for me it is still a mystery how I can navigate through the elements of `attachments` and, moreover, save both the fields of elements `attachments` and the field `doc_id` that is outside `jsonb` into other table at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You can treat `jsonb_array_elements(...)` as a table to join on, so the query producing your table is

```
select doc_id,
       cast(attachment ->> 'size' as integer) as size,
       attachment ->> 'type' as type,
       attachment ->> 'storageId' as document_storage_id
from _book, jsonb_array_elements(data->'attachments') as attachment;
```

and from there you can construct `_doc` using the INSERT..SELECT form:

```
insert into _doc
select doc_id,
       cast(attachment ->> 'size' as integer) as size,
       attachment ->> 'type' as type,
       attachment ->> 'storageId' as document_storage_id
from _book, jsonb_array_elements(data->'attachments') as attachment;
```